# Do stress and strain contradict each other?

Tags: elasticity, stress-strain, matter

According to the book Engineering Physics by R.K Gaur and S.L Gupta

Strain: Strain is a fractional deformation produced in the body when it is subjected to set of deforming forces.

Stress: The Internal forces called into play to restore it to its original state.

The book also noted that stress and strain accompany each other

My question here is (Title) because when there fractional deformation the body can never get back into its original state or equilibrium or vice versa. What is going wrong here is my interpretation of the book wrong or the author forget to mention something?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: In linear elasticity, they are intimately related through the elastic tensor.

Comment: *"when there fractional deformation the body can never get back into its original state"* Strange statement. Reading into the quoted definitions, as soon as the body is relieved of the external deforming forces, the stress will act to move it back into the original state.